# React Material-Table custom pagination not allowing to override default rowsPerPage value

Tags: reactjs, pagination, material-table

I am using React Material-Table. To implement server-side rendering, I have overridden the pagination component of  as below:-

````
    Pagination: props => (
        <TablePagination
            {...props}
            emptyRowsWhenPaging={false}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[10,20,30,40]}
            rowsPerPage={10}
            count={55}
            page={page}
            onChangePage={(e, page) => {
                setPage(page)
            }}

        />
    )
}}```
As can be seen above, rowsPerPage is set to 10, so that I get 10 rows per page.
However, the page always shows 5 rows by default initially.
Am I missing something?
````